# How to find element based on what its value ends with in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am dealing with a situation where every time I login a report is displayed in a table whose ID is dynamically generated with random text ending with "table".

I am automating this table with selenium  python web driver. It has Syntax

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="isc_43table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[11]').click();
```

help me editing this syntax to match it with table ending id with `"table"`.
(only one table is generated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ends-with`](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide5/xpath-ends-with) [XPath Constraint Function](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide5/xpath-constraint-functions) is part of **XPath v2.0** but as per the current implementation *Selenium* supports **XPath v1.0**.

As per the *HTML* you have shared to identify the element you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `XPath` using [`contains()`](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide5/xpath-contains):

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'table')]/tbody/tr[1]/td[11]").click();
  ```
- Further, as you have mentioned that *table whose ID is dynamically generated* so to invoke `click()` on the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'table')]/tbody/tr[1]/td[11]"))).click()
  ```
- Alternatively, you can also use *CssSelector* as:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id$='table']>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(11)").click();
  ```
- Again, you can also use *CssSelector* inducing *WebDriverWait* as:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id$='table']>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(11)"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: @gurpreetbal [Selenium Documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html) and [selenium-python.readthedocs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) are the 2 basic documentation where you can learn almost everything about web automation using selenium python.

Answer (score 2):

I hope, either these 2 will work for you

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[ends-with(@id,'table')]/tbody/tr[1]/td[11]").click();
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[substring(@id,'table')]/tbody/tr[1]/td[11]").click();
```

If not getting, remove the tags from tbody.

For such situations, when you face randomly generated ids, you can use the below functions with XPATH expression

1) Contains,

2) Starts-with &

3) Ends-with

4) substring

**Syntax**

`//table[ends-with(@id,'table')]`

`//h4/a[contains(text(),'SAP M')]`

`//div[substring(@id,'table')]`

You need to identify the element which is having that id, whether its div or input or table. I think its a table.

Comment: Neither `//table[ends-with(@id,'table')]` nor `//table[substring(@id,'table')]` will work...

Answer (score 1):

You can try below XPath to simulate `ends-with()` syntax:

```
'//table[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length("table") +1) = "table"]//tr[1]/td[11]'
```

You can also use CSS selector:

```
'table[id$="table"] tr>td:nth-of-type(11)'
```