# How to identify the select tag with dynamic ID using XPath ends-with through C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I can't seem to get the correct XPath syntax to find this select element that has a dynamic start to the ID field but ends with static data.

```
<select name="" autocomplete="off" id="edlbpDesktopFfqp_B005WJQUJ4-predefinedQuantitiesDropdown" tabindex="-1" class="a-native-dropdown">
                        <option value="1" selected="">
                            1
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            2
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            3
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            4
                        </option>
                </select>
```

I've tried both of these unsuccessfully:

```
var dd = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[ends-with(@id,'predefinedQuantitiesDropdown')]"));
dd.Click();
```

AND

```
var dd = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id, 'predefinedQuantitiesDropdown')]"));
dd.Click();
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ends-with`](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide5/xpath-ends-with) [XPath Constraint Function](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide5/xpath-constraint-functions) is part of **XPath v2.0** but as per the current implementation *Selenium* supports **XPath v1.0**.

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to find element based on what its value ends with in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442191/how-to-find-element-based-on-what-its-value-ends-with-in-selenium/51442252#51442252)

As the element is a dynamic element to `Click()` on the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *ElementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("select.a-native-dropdown[id$='predefinedQuantitiesDropdown']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//select[@class='a-native-dropdown' and contains(@id, 'predefinedQuantitiesDropdown')]"))).Click();
  ```

**Note**:However as per the *best practices* as the desired element is a `<select>` tag, so ideally you need to use the [SelectElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/) Class and it's methods from [OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/N_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI.htm) namespace to select any option.

Comment: Worked perfectly and thank you for the fantastic explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Select` class to select item from drop down.You can try any of the below method.Hope this helps.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;



 Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id ,'predefinedQuantitiesDropdown')]")));

   select.selectByVisibleText("1"); //text visible on drop down
   select.selectByValue("1");     //value attribute on option tag
   select.selectByIndex(1);       //Index 1,2....n
```